# mat-checkbox does not update checked state when I change its model in jasmine unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine

I wrote a unit test for material check box. I used [(ngModule)] to bind check-box to the model. the first test case is ok, clicking on the checkbox will update the model however when I change the model in the next unit test, It does not happen. In other words, when I set enabled to true, the checked state does not change to true!
How can I pass the last unit test?
The code is uploaded to [github](https://github.com/hgaleh/angular-tests/tree/master/src/app/material/checkbox)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './checkbox.component.html'
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
  enabled = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}


describe('CheckboxComponent', () => {
  let component: CheckboxComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CheckboxComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CheckboxComponent ],
      imports: [
        MatCheckboxModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CheckboxComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('click checkbox changes enabled', () => {
    const checkBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    expect(component.enabled).toBeFalse();
    checkBox.click();
    expect(component.enabled).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('changing enabled will alter checkbox state', (done) => {
    const checkBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    component.enabled = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(checkBox.checked).toBeTrue();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="enabled">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding another detectChanges() in whenStable()

```
it('changing enabled will alter checkbox state', (done) => {
const checkBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
component.enabled = true;
fixture.detectChanges();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges(); // <--- this line
  expect(checkBox.checked).toBeTrue();
  done();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need a new reference to the DOM/HTML. `checkbox` refers to the old DOM before the `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Try this:

```
it('changing enabled will alter checkbox state', (done) => {
    const checkBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    component.enabled = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const newCheckbox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement as HTMLInputElement; // grab new reference
      expect(newCheckbox.checked).toBeTrue();
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't affect anything.